# wrong in creating string array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, string

all:

I want to create a string array and then pass it to a class in python as following:

```
from plottert import plotter
at[0]='./Re100/17/0.001/R/Vx-H'
at[1]='./Re100/33/0.001/R/Vx-H'
at[2]='./Re100/65/0.001/R/Vx-H'
b[0]='./U-0.001-H'
plotter (at,b)
```

but I got an error showing `name 'at' is not defined`. 
I know that `at.append()` will do work. But, what I really want is to add the value to a SPECIFIC index of the array I want. Any help?

Comment: You never create your list.

Comment: If `name 'at' is not defined`, `at.append()` won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply fill it with empty strings if you want

```
at = [''] * n #n = length of list
at[0]='./Re100/17/0.001/R/Vx-H'
at[1]=...
```

However as others have mentioned, you never initialized your list in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

First, create the lists (there is no non-basic-type [arrays](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html)):

```
at = [''] * n # n = size of at
b = [''] * m # m = size of b
```

then execute your code.

You cant use lists you havent defined.

Comment: This is a [list](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list), not an [array](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html).

Comment: @Matthias He tried to store an string into an 'array', so i supposed he mean list, since you cannot store non-basic-types like strings into a position in the 'array'. I'll change the name since you feel unconfortable...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign to indexes without having to know the final size of your data structure, use a dictionary instead:

```
at = {}
at[0] = 'zero'
at[4] = 'four'  # look, it's sparse
```

As you can see, this also has the advantage (over append) that you can assign in any order.

If you want to convert this to an array later, you can do something like this:

```
at_arr = [at[i] if i in at else None
          for i in range(max(at.keys())+1)]
# at_arr now holds the array ['zero', None, None, None, 'four']
```